# How to change the number of stores showed into the left panel with Google storelocator library?

Tags: javascript, gps, maps

I'm using the Store Locator Library for Maps API that you can find [here](http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/index.html?utm_source=geoblog&utm_campaign=sl)
I've customized the custom.html example like I need.
The last thing that I need to do is: change the default value of stores showed to the left panel from 10 to all stores inserted in the .csv file. How can I change it? Could somebody help me please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The line of code you need to change is found in 'store-locator.compiled.js'.

```
for( var b = function(){ a[A]( this.store, d ) }, i = 0, k = h.min( 10, c[B] ); i < k; i++ )
```

Search for the above line and change the '10' to whatever you require.